# Defining a homotopy between maps transforming coffee mug to a donut

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Assume that we have two topological spaces $X$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ and two continuous maps $f_1,f_2$ such that $f_1 :X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ and $f_2 : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.

**My first question** is that can I assume that $f_1(X)$ is a coffee mug in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $f_2(X)$ is a donut in $\mathbb{R}^3$ without adding any constraints?

If so, how can I define a *homotopy* between $f_1$ and $f_2$? Do I have to know the rule of these maps or just say there exist a homotopy?

Comment: No. You can't. You don't  know the exact nature of $f_1$. A coffee mug is homeomorphic to torus which has fundamental group isomorphic to $Z \directsum Z$. But $f_1(X)$ may be simply connected. You never know.

Comment: I don't understand your first question. Are $X,f_1,f_2$ arbitrary or have you chosen them? For example, if $X$ is a single-point space, then $f_1(X)$ and $f_2(X)$ will be single points in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so certainly won't be (homeomorphic or homotopic to) a coffee mug and a donut.

Comment: Do you want $X$ to be the Torus? If so just do whatever this gif does. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mug_and_Torus_morph.gif

Comment: @joy, Do I have to know the fundamental groups of the images of $f_1$ and $f_2$ to define a homotopy between them?

Comment: @Clive Newstead, of course $X$ is not a single-point set. I just want to assume that somehow the image of $X$ under $f_1$ is a coffee mug and under $f_2$, a donut.

Comment: Not necessarily. But I just cited a counter-example, nothing else.

Comment: Are you asking whether two maps $f_{1}$, $f_{2}:X \to \mathbf{R}^{3}$ are homotopic (answer: yes), and if so, how to exhibit a homotopy (obvious choice: the straight-line homotopy $$H(x, t) = (1 - t)f_{1}(x) + tf_{2}(x),\quad x \in X,\ 0 \leq t \leq 1),$$or are you getting at something else?

Comment: I was asking how to exhibit a homotopy and straight-line homotopy is just fine. Are there any others?

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Answering the question as clarified in the comments:

> If $X$ is a topological space, and if $f_{1}$, $f_{2}:X \to \Reals^{3}$ are continuous, how can I define a homotopy between $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$?

Because $\Reals^{3}$ has operations of addition and scalar multiplication, you can get an infinite-dimensional family of homotopies by picking continuous, real-valued functions $\tau_{1}$ and $\tau_{2}$ on $[0, 1]$ that satisfy
$$
\tau_{1}(0) = 1 = \tau_{2}(1),\qquad
\tau_{1}(1) = 0 = \tau_{2}(0),
$$
and defining
$$
H(x, t) = \tau_{1}(t) f_{1}(x) + \tau_{2}(t) f_{2}(x).
\tag{1}
$$
The *straight-line homotopy* results from taking
\begin{align*}
\tau_{1}(t) &= 1 - t, \\
\tau_{2}(t) &= 1 - \tau_{1}(t) = t.
\end{align*}
(Generally, the values of $\tau_{i}$ need not stay within $[0, 1]$, and the functions need not satisfy $\tau_{1} + \tau_{2} = 1$.)

As of May 2016, the [Raphaël JavaScript Library](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/) (with which I have no affiliation) has [animation demos](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/bounce.html) showing the visual effect of using non-linear $\tau_{i}$ in (1).

This is by no means all, in the same sense that a general function of two variables $(x, t)$ is not a sum of products of functions of the individual variables as in (1). (That, in turn, is a little like saying "a general function of one variable is not constant.")